# org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group, can this class actually be scrolled

Tags: java, swt, scrollable

The class `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group` inherits from `Composite` which inherits from `Scrollable`. However, when I call the inherited method `getVerticalScrollBar()`, it always returns `null`.

Is it possible to make a `Group` scrollable? If it is possible, how?

BTW, the `Group` contains a number of `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button.Button` styled as `SWT.CHECK`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get the `Group` scrollable itself. However, I managed to achieve the same effect by adding a [`ScrolledComposite`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html) to the `Group`:

```
group = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
group.setText("Images: ");
group.setLayout(new FillLayout());

ScrolledComposite comp = new ScrolledComposite(group, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
comp.setLayout(new FillLayout());

Composite innerComp = new Composite(comp, SWT.NONE);
innerComp.setLayout(new FillLayout());

comp.setContent(innerComp);
comp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
comp.setExpandVertical(true);
```

Afterwards you can add your `Button`s to the `Composite` `innerComp`. It might be necessary to use `setMinHeight(int height)` and `setMinWidth(int width)` on the `ScrolledComposite`.

**EDIT**

Here is a small working example. If you decrease the size of the window, you will see, that the scrollbars will appear:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Group imageGroup = new Group(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    imageGroup.setText("Images: ");
    imageGroup.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    ScrolledComposite frontComp = new ScrolledComposite(imageGroup, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    Composite innerFrontComp = new Composite(frontComp, SWT.NONE);
    frontComp.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    innerFrontComp.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    new Button(innerFrontComp, SWT.CHECK).setText("Button");
    new Button(innerFrontComp, SWT.CHECK).setText("Button");
    new Button(innerFrontComp, SWT.CHECK).setText("Button");
    new Button(innerFrontComp, SWT.CHECK).setText("Button");
    new Button(innerFrontComp, SWT.CHECK).setText("Button");
    new Button(innerFrontComp, SWT.CHECK).setText("Button");
    new Button(innerFrontComp, SWT.CHECK).setText("Button");
    new Button(innerFrontComp, SWT.CHECK).setText("Button");

    frontComp.setMinHeight(innerFrontComp.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);
    frontComp.setMinWidth(innerFrontComp.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).x);
    frontComp.setContent(innerFrontComp);
    frontComp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    frontComp.setExpandVertical(true);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while(!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if(!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try your solution however my buttons are no longer visible. There must be an attribute I need to enable. So far I tried settting both the comp and innerComp visible.

Comment: @user1464251 I added a small working example. Run it, decrease the window size and the scrollbars will appear...

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/javadoc.php) of SWT says:

> Returns the receiver's vertical scroll bar if it has one, and null if it does not.

If the user makes the window/dialog smaller, then the scroll-bar appears. Only then will the methods `getVerticalScrollBar()` and `getHorizontalScrollBar()` return a non-null value. You must always check for `null` when it comes to this. It's just the way SWT is built.

Edit: Try calling the `getVerticalScrollBar()` method on a `Composite` or on a `Shell` instead.

Comment: Well this is the issue, there are more buttons than can be displayed in the group. The getVerticalScrollBar() method still returns null.

Comment: @user1464251 Are you absolutely sure of this ? It just doesn't make any sense... I currently work on a project that involves heavy usage of SWT and I've seen this null/non-null `ScrollBar` in action...

Comment: I agree, it doesn't make sense to me either. However this is exactly what I am observing.

Comment: still getting null. I have to assume it believes all elements are visible, however as already stated, that is not the case.